# Why is it CORS response is not still appended after setting it on server side?

Tags: angularjs, express

I have a login module which is hosted on `localhost:5000/login` which is the SPA and authenticate it on `localhost:2000/users/login` which is another SPA.

Here's my code for the client side in the first SPA:

```
app.service('loginService',  ['$http', '$log','$window', function($http,$log,$window) {

    function loginCredentials(data, callback) {
        $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $http.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = constants.content_type;

        console.log('I got here in loginService')
        // call localhost:2000/users/login
        $http.post('localhost:2000/users/login')
        // Then a promise follows

});
```

Then here's the route I'm trying to access in `localhost:2000/users/login`

```
app.post('/users/login', function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { return res.json(err); }
      if (!user) { return res.json( { error: info.error, message: info.message }); }

      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR: " + err);
          return next(err);
        }

        console.log("Login Successful!");
        return res.json(user);
      });
    })(req,res,next);
});
```

And this is what I get:

```
I got here in login credentials
:5000/login:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2000/users/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In a nutshell: There's no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the `localhost:2000/users/login` response message when I access it with `localhost:5000/login`. Despite setting it up in the server side.

Why is this?

Comment: are you getting this error on chrome ? chrome blocks cross origin requests

Comment: Are you sure it's not being caused by an `OPTIONS` preflight request? That would never hit your POST route.

Comment: @dennyjohn Yes. But I wanted to know how would I make it work on chrome. Especially if the user doesn't know about this kind of stuff.

Comment: @robertklep What do you mean `OPTIONS` preflight request? And how does it not hit my POST route?

Comment: @LouieCubero for particular content-types (like `application/json`), your browser will issue an `OPTIONS` request _before_ the `POST` request. If that `OPTIONS` request fails, the `POST` request will never be made. It's probably better to use a middleware like [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to handle the CORS details.

Comment: Hmm I see, I'll check up on to that. Thanks for the tip @robertklep! :)