# Why is Angular response still showing 0 status, instead of 401 after setting up API CORS policy?

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the following API setup:

- A .NET Core API deployed to AWS Lambda, using AWS API Gateway.
- Authentication implemented on the AWS API Gateway level.
- CORS configured within my .NET Startup.cs file as the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // This is first in the method.
            services.AddCors(
                options => options.AddPolicy(
                    "AllowAll",
                    p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()));
...
```

--and--

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // This is first in the method.
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");

...
```

I have an Angular front-end app that makes the requests to the API.

When I get an authentication token and pass it along in the request, everything works well and as expected.

** However, when the token is missing or expired, my Angular HTTP response code is 0--not 401.

When I look at the request/responses in Fiddler:
- I can see the pre-flight HTTP OPTIONS request and response. The response has all the headers returned: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
- I can see the followup HTTP POST request and response. It correctly returns a 401 response.

Why is my Angular response still showing 0 status, instead of 401? I have seen many, many questions/answers that point to the CORS configuration, but I 'm almost positive I have it setup correctly.

Similar question, but not really answered: [Why is it CORS response is not still appended after setting it on server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567687/why-is-it-cors-response-is-not-still-appended-after-setting-it-on-server-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this one myself.  It appears that the Dotnet Core unhandled exception handling returns the error response without the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

I was overriding the exception handler to format error information in a consistent manner when I ran into this.  What I did was to set the header at the top of the exception handler:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
  {
    errorApp.Run(async context =>
    {
      // Add CORS header to allow error message to be visible to Angular
      if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin", out StringValues origin))
      {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin.ToString());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
try out using this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ...

    // global policy - assign here or on each controller
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    // ...

    // IMPORTANT: Make sure UseCors() is called BEFORE this
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

For more information ,Visit this [LINK](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/26/aspnet-core-and-cors-gotchas)

Comment: In my .NET API, I do set the CORS stuff first--as seen in my code sample.

Comment: Did you use the `app.Mvc()` @user11541698

Comment: Visit the link , If it can help you . @user11541698